# Xcode 6 Auto Layout - Simulator has correct display, Storyboard far off

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to figure out the reason why my storyboard's auto layout are extremely far off, but in my simulator the elements appear exactly how I want them to. I am using the iPhone 6 simulator, Storyboard Simulated Metrics size is set to iPhone 4-inch and I applied the constraints with a w:Any and h:Any. See below for the drastic differences in UI placement. Is this a bug or is this related to size of phone in storyboard vs simulator? (Disregard changes to imageview shape)

[image: storyboard placement]
[image: simulator placement]

**EDIT** ---------------------

Here are the Constraints for each element:

registrationBackgroundImage:

[image: background image]

profileImagePlaceHolder:

[image: placeholder]

textfields:

[image: textfields]

All Constraints:

[image: all constraints]

I'm not sure if this is the best way to show everyone so sorry in advance if there is a better way.

Comment: what constraints did you set up?

Comment: Haven't you misplaced view warnings?

Comment: @Azat there are no misplaced view warnings.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what constraints you have on the image view.

Comment: @rdelmar I just edited my question to add screenshots of the image view. Sorry if this is not the best way to show everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure why it looks ok in the storyboard, but it would be better to make the top constraint of profileImagePlaceHolder: to the bottom of the registrationBackgroundImage:, not to the top layout guide. That will ensure that you have whatever spacing you want between those two views.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! You are heading for a crash. Your constraints are overdetermined. If you  have set the trailing and leading space for something, do _not_ also set its width. (By the way, the reason you have not noticed this crash yet is that you have used the iPhone 4-inch simulated metrics as a crutch. Big mistake. Design your interface in the neutral "big square"; this will help you use constraints properly.)

Comment: @matt maybe only those of us "of a certain age" will get that cultural reference. My wife used that one just yesterday  -:)

Comment: @matt . Thanks for all of the advice. This has been extremely helpful. If I'm only designing for say iPhone portraits, would it be safe to use the iPhone 4-inch simulated metrics as a crutch and apply my constraints to only to compact width, regular height?

Comment: I can only advise. My advice is: Design in the neutral square and design for all size classes (w:Any, h:Any). You will learn more and you will be safer.

Comment: Incidentally it is a _big_ mistake to design for a particular size class from the outset. That may be the source of some of your troubles. You _must_ design for Any, Any. Use the specific size classes only for _modifications_ of Any, Any (i.e. to vary from it). It is unfortunate that Interface Builder does not enforce this.

Comment: @matt thanks for all of the great advice. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

**StoryBoard is not intended to show a preview :**

*Examples :*

- you can't see rounded corners until it is processed
- you can't see appearance modifications from code (i.e. : increasing/decreasing constraint value)
- you can't see alpha changes
- ...

***So sometimes you may see storyboard rendering different from simulator where all is processed.***

### btw, it is nice on simulator, good job!